# Why this overdetermined system has no solutions in general?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, diffeomorphism

Suppose functions $a_{ij}: \mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}$ are given. The task is to find a diffeomorphism $y:U(x^{0})\to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that $$\displaystyle \sum\limits_{i,j=1}^{n}a_{ij}(x(y))\dfrac{\partial y_{k}}{\partial x_{i}}\dfrac{\partial y_{l}}{\partial x_{j}} = 0$$ for every $y\in V(y^{0})$ -- some neighborhood of $y^{0}$ (in the standart topology of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$). The function $x(y)$ is the inverse of $y$. Let's also suppose that $a_{ij}(x)\equiv a_{ji}(x)$

The desired diffeomorphism is $y = (y_{1},\ldots,y_{n})$, so we want to find $n$ functions, however they must satisfy $(n^2-n)/2$ equiations. So our system is *overdetermined*. Why such system does not have solutions (provided $n>3$) in general? One could just construct $a_{ij}$ and work out the example, but is there more straightforward approach to show that such system is inconsistent in general?

Comment: I would like to know what is the difference between overdetermined and "under"determined systems in such cases (it is a system of functional equations): why "under"determined system is more likely (whatever that means) to have a solution than an overdetermined one? Is it even the case?

Comment: If you let $A$ be the matrix whose element in the $i$-th row and $j$-th column is $a_{ij}$ and define the matrix $B$ where $$B^j_k = \frac{\partial y^j}{\partial x^k},$$ then your equation is equivalent to $$ BAB^t = 0. $$ If $A$ is not the zero matrix, then this equation never holds if $B$ is invertible. Perhaps you meant to ask something else?

Comment: In some textbooks on equations of mathematical physics it is said that one can find a transformation, so that at some point $x^{0}\in G\subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ terms $\tilde{a}_{ij}(x^{0}) = 0$, where $\tilde{a}_{ij}$ is defind as an element of matrix $\tilde{A} = BAB^{T}$. In the case $n=2$ one could even make $\tilde{a}_{ij} = 0$ at some neighborhood. However, when $n>3$ it is said that it is not longer possible to guarantee that we can make it, the only possibility is to annul it at some single point due to the fact that the system is overdetermined.

Comment: My question is how to rigorously prove that

Comment: Could you provide the context for this statement and perhaps a reference?